# How do I use a conda environment with mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, anaconda, conda

My first post, and I'm new to both Python and Apache, so please go easy on me.  I have a Python web application in a conda environment that serves up content just fine using Flask.  Now I need to serve everything with Apache instead of Flask.  I can get Apache to run Python with mod_wsgi, but only with virtualenv.  I tried installing virtualenv with Anaconda, but I received a warning that such a setup is unsupported and not recommended.  So my question is this:

How do I set up Apache to run my application in a conda environment?

[Here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/), there's a section on working with virtual environments, and it says I need to enter a line into my wsgi file showing where to find activate_this.py.  A virtualenv virtual environment has activate_this.py, but a conda environment does not.  It seems that without the right instructions for activating the virtual environment, I'm just getting error 500 in my browser and "Import error: no module named flask" in my httpd error_log.

This is in my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot /var/www
     WSGIScriptAlias / var/www/tsm.wsgi
     <Directory /var/www/tsm>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is tsm.wsgi:

```
import sys
import site
site.addsitedir('~/.conda/envs/tsm/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/tsm/server/time_series_machine')
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
from app import app as application
```

Any ideas?  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm late to the party on this but I was having the same problem. For what its worth, I didn't have to recompile anything and was able to get this to work by including something like this in my VirtualHost configuration using the system-installed mod_wsgi:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/path/to/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Note that this points to the `site-packages` directory.

Comment: Which file are you refering to here?

Comment: This file is the OP `httpd.conf` file.

Answer (score 9):

To add to @dino's answer, you can also install `mod_wsgi` into your root conda environment:

```
# Instal `mod_wsgi`
$ pip install mod_wsgi

# Find the full path to installed `mod_wsgi`
$ which mod_wsgi-express

# Install and register the `mod_wsgi` module with Apache
$ sudo /full/path/to/installed/mod_wsgi-express install-module
```

You can then create conda environments for multiple sites:

```
# Create 3 conda environments
conda create -n mysite1 python django
conda create -n mysite2 python django
conda create -n mysite3 python django
```

And set `WSGIDaemonProcess` in the Apache site configuration file to use the appropriate environment for each site:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite1.conf
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite1 python-path=/path/to/anaconda3/envs/mysite1/lib/python3.5/site-packages

# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite2.conf
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite2 python-path=/path/to/anaconda3/envs/mysite2/lib/python3.5/site-packages

# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite3.conf
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite3 python-path=/path/to/anaconda3/envs/mysite3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Comment: @graham-dumpleton Can you provide an explanation for the edit? I tried it out on a local machine and I get errors in my apache log file saying `ImportError: No module named 'django'`.

Comment: Using ``python-path`` to refer to ``site-packages`` is not best practice. You should use ``python-home`` option to refer to the top of the Python virtual environment instead. Referring to ``site-packages`` can hide various problems such as your mod_wsgi actually being compiled for a different Python version or installation. http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html

Comment: The site configuration files inside `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` folder (see the comments in the code snippets).

Answer (score 3):

Your mod_wsgi would need to be compiled against Anaconda Python to start with and not your system Python. In other words you cannot use the system supplied mod_wsgi packages but would need to compile it yourself. Then follow what it says in:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html

That is, use daemon mode and use the `python-home` option to `WSGIDaemonProcess`.

Do note that there have been reports suggesting that Anaconda Python is broken in some way and will not work with systems that want to embed Python. So may not work anyway.

BTW, you cannot use '~' in the path in your WSGI script file anyway with the way you were doing it. It would not be expanded to be the home directory. But then, follow that post and you will not need that.

Comment: Thanks!  I think...  I think that fixed it.  I'm running into other errors now, but I think I have an Apache server using mod_wsgi in a conda environment.  I yum removed mod_wsgi, downloaded the source code, source activated my conda environment, compiled and installed with "python setup.py install," and then I started up a server with mod_wsgi-express start-server on 0.0.0.0:8080.  I could see the page there... a snake in a bottle?  But now when I try loading a specific .py file I get this error:

Comment: Sorry, hit enter instead of shift-enter, then took too long to correct my response.  Anyway, I think it's working; I'm just getting a different error now when trying to run a simple helloWorld.py and I'll work on that for now, submit another question later if I can't figure it out.  Thanks again.